# Problem with Bootstrap 4 footer when used with Angular

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, flexbox, footer

I'm trying to make Bootstrap 4 footer stick to the bottom of the page. I am setting mt-auto class on the footer element and flex and h-100 on html and body.

It works as expected if all code is within one index.html file. However if I transfer the footer part to a component, the mt-auto doesn't seem to work and the footer is not pushed to the bottom.

app.component.html:

```
<footer class="mt-auto"> 
  <div class="container">
    Footer text goes here.
  </div>
</footer>
```

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class="h-100">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Sticky Footer</title>
    <base href="/">
  </head>
  <body class="d-flex flex-column h-100">
    <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can try to set in component css `:host{ height: 100%; }`

Comment: That worked, thanks! Didn't realize angular elements could have styles applied as well.

Comment: @bolshas What was the final working code?